# textscan delimiter = "abc" does not work

Tags: regex, matlab, textscan

I am trying to read a text file that has textual data and separated by delimiter say `'abc'` as consecutive characters separating the string that I want to read.

Ex: say `text.txt` file, as follows:

```
John abc Mike abc Micheal

Sandra abc Sarah abc David
```

I tried the following code but it did not work because delimiter is NOT a single character:

```
user = textscan(fid, '%s%s%s','Delimiter','abc');
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use a [regular expression](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html):

```
user = regexp(str, 'abc', 'split')
```

where `str` is a (cell)string read with something like:

```
str = textscan(fid, '%s','Delimiter','\n')
```

Comment: Throws this error - `All cells must be strings.`. Instead if you use `str = importdata(filename)` works.

Comment: Thanks Rody. I spent 1 day tweeking and tweeking codes until your answer came... thanks again.

Comment: Thanks Divakar. I consolidate your add with my code and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick:

```
user = textscan(fid, '%s%s%s', 'delimiter', {'abc'});
```

Comment: Ah ok. I use R2013a. It works there. Don't know solution for 2010b.

Comment: Thanks Marcin. This exactly what I have done and the problem was persist. Thanks again.